# Formidable Upload Not Working: 'files" undefined, no error

Tags: node.js, file-upload, formidable

I'm trying to upload a file using formidable, following the tutorial in the [Node Beginner Book](http://www.nodebeginner.org/). Following this code, I have a server modules that passes the `request` object to a requestHandler module. The main page loads a form with the following handler:

```
function start(response) {
    console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");

    var body = '<html>'+
        '<head>'+
        '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; '+
        'charset=UTF-8" />'+
        '</head>'+
        '<body>'+
        '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data method="post">'+
        '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"'+
        '<input type="submit" value="Upload file" />'+
        '</form>'+
        '</body>'+
        '</html>';

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write(body);
    response.end();

}
```

When the form is submitted, the /upload path triggers the following upload handler function:

```
function upload(response,request) {
    console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    console.log("about to parse");
    form.parse(request, function(error, fields, files) {
        console.log("parsing done");

        console.log(util.inspect({error: error, fields: fields, files: files}));

        fs.rename(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png", function(error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                fs.unlink("/tmp/test.png");
                fs.rename(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png");
            }
        });
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        response.write("received image:<br/>");
        response.write("<img src='/show' />");
        reponse.end();
    });

}
```

When the upload button is clicked, however, the server crashes with the following error:

```
/home/****/Coding/nodebeginner/requestHandlers.js:38
        fs.rename(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png", function(erro
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
    at /home/****/Coding/nodebeginner/requestHandlers.js:38:25
    at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (/home/****/Coding/nodebeginner/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:104:9)
    at IncomingForm.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at IncomingForm._maybeEnd (/home/****/Coding/nodebeginner/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:551:8)
    at Object.end (/home/****/Coding/nodebeginner/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:238:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/****/Coding/nodebeginner/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:129:30)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

So evidently the `files` variable is undefined. I thought there might be an error, but no the `error` variable is set to `null`. So I'm a bit stumped here. Ideas?

Comment: Which server module are you using? Typically, or at least in the default `createServer` and in Express.js, the parameter order is `request, response`, so perhaps it's `undefined` because `upload(response,request)` *should be* `upload(request,response)`? Also you're missing an ending quote after `multipart/form-data`

Comment: Right, now I'm getting a new error: /home/ethan/Coding/nodebeginner/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:301
  if (this.headers['content-length']) {
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'content-length' of undefined

Comment: Were you able to fix it? I'm doing the same tutorial and having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also having the same issue. Your form tag is missing a closing double quote(") on the enctype attribute.

Comment: I think this is the right answer -- I was getting the exact same error on this tutorial; turns out I also had a typo in my form data: "multipart-form-date" instead of "multipart-form-data". Fixing this solved the problem for me. I see another typo in the question's code snippet: the first <input is missing a closing />

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.
    I think you see those line code on Node Beginner Book, at the end of the book.
    I fixed it by removed follow code on server.js file:

> ```
> //      req.setEncoding("utf8");
> //        req.addListener("data", function(postDataChunk) {
> //            postData += postDataChunk;
> //        });
> //        req.addListener("end", function() {
> //            route(handle, pathname, res, req);
> //        });
> ```

```
Just do:
```

> route(handle, pathname, res, req);

```
And last, you must be careful at html form tags.

Sorry for my English and best wishes!

***VinRover Nguyen***
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got stuck at the same issue.
Sounds like upload class have been replaced or misspelled.
Try to change the reference from files.upload.path to files.Upload.path .
It works here.
Check out the master branch for further information : [Git](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/tree/master/lib)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some errors in your "var body".
Try :

```
var body = '<html>' +
  '<head>' +
  '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />' +
  '</head>' +
  '<body>' +
  '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">' +
  '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple">' +
  '<input type="submit" value="Upload File">' +
  '</form>' +
  '</bidy>' +
  '</html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the names of the parameters for the callback in form.parse.

The Node Beginner Book shows the code as:

```
form.parse(request, function(error, fields, files) {
    //code
}
```

The parameters should not be plural in the callback function:

```
form.parse(request, function(error, field, file) {
    //code
}
```

Take a look at IncomingForm.prototype.parse in /node_modlues/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js.  The callback is listening for singular "field" and "file" .

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but if someone still comes across this in 2023, please try below.

```
const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

form.parse(req, async (error, fields, files) => {
  if (error) {        
    console.error(`Error at form.parse: ${error}`);
    return res.status(500).send(`Error handling upload request.`);
  } 

  if (!files || !files.file) {
    console.error(`No file received.`);
    return res.status(400).send('No file received.');
  }

//Your code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the enctype, you have a syntax error. In the original question the enctype attribute isn't closed... I was having an undefined files Param because I forgot to include an enctype in my html... `<form action="run" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` A correct enctype attribute in the form html is the solution. Then the files Param has the name attribute of the file input as a property name and the variable itself is an Object containing many keys, like... `files["name-attribute"].filepath;` There was probably an error produced but not in the node terminal, in the client browser console. Missing a quote like in your example is a simple syntax error in the html that doesn't run until the browser opens it. So node won't know there was an error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

With the latest Node Js - I think its an array and should be accessed like the below

var oldpath = files.filetoupload[0].filepath;

This is how the multipart form posts data.

```
{
  filetoupload: [
    PersistentFile {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      lastModifiedDate: 2023-12-15T14:14:39.405Z,
      filepath: 'C:\\Users\\dquadros\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\14\\8d2f315816a0ede813164c800',
      newFilename: '8d2f315816a0ede813164c800',
      originalFilename: 'ppreport.pdf',
      mimetype: 'application/pdf',
      hashAlgorithm: false,
      size: 193138,
      _writeStream: [WriteStream],
      hash: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  ]
}
```